# How to find the user agent string for LinkedIn app browser from iOS

Tags: user-agent

What is the user-agent string added when we open LinkedIn app from an IOS mobile. I want to detect LinkedIn app from IOS using user-agent string, is that achievable. Are there unique user-agent strings for different devices for LinkedIn app

Comment: You can capture the network packet using [these methods](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/remote-packet-capture-for-ios-devices.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have been in the situation where we needed to quickly find the UAs for facebook, Twitter and other apps that use webviews on iOS.

We ended up using a service on [udger.com](https://udger.com/resources/online-parser)
This gives you the string quickly if you open the site in the service. (send yourself a facebook message with the link or something like that.)

I am sure that there are multiple other services like udger, but that was the one we ended up on.

Answer (score 5):

**It doesn't seem like LinkedIn has a specific user agent string for the app browser.**

From using udger (opening an udger link from LinkedIn Messages on native mobile App for iPhone) I got the following:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_2_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/13D15
```

Which differs heavily from one you get from the FB browser which looks like this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU iPhone OS 5_1_1 like Mac OS X; en_US) AppleWebKit (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile [FBAN/FBForIPhone;FBAV/4.1.1;FBBV/4110.0;FBDV/iPad2,1;FBMD/iPad;FBSN/iPhone OS;FBSV/5.1.1;FBSS/1; FBCR/;FBID/tablet;FBLC/en_US;FBSF/1.0]
```

The main difference being the **Mobile/13D15**, but unfortunately that has no correlation with LinkedIn, but only with the Mobile Build number.

If you've gotten any new progress on this issue feel free to reply!